# How to handle the click on the cell in the GXT 2.2 grid?

Tags: java, gwt, grid, cell, gxt

I'm looking for the way to handle the cell click. How to do this if I create a new column in grid in this way:

```
column = new ColumnConfig();
column.setId("remove");
column.setHeader("Remove");
column.setWidth(100);        
configs.add(column);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle cell clicks on the grid to which the `ColumnConfig` belongs.
For example, say you have `Grid grid = new Grid(new ColumnModel(column));`, then:

```
grid.addListener(Events.CellDoubleClick, new Listener<GridEvent>() {
    public void handleEvent(GridEvent be) {
        // be.getColIndex() gets the index of the column clicked on.
        // if you know the index of `column`, you can compare that number to the colIndex
        // if the numbers are equal, do whatever you want to do
        // see docs for GridEvent at 
        // http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/event/GridEvent.html
    }
});
```

Comment: And for regular click, add a `Events.CellClick` listener.

Comment: Right - typo on my part in my answer, I meant to put `CellClick`, but copied the wrong Events name. :)

Comment: @thy_stack_overfloweth I am facing the similar issue can pls look and suggest the solution Here is my Question http://stackoverflow.com/q/22610705/3277781