# How to migrate from GXT 2.2.3 to GXT 3.0.1

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I created EditorGrid using GXT 2.2.3.Everything required is over.But at one point I stucked i.e I need to disable and enable some cells based on the value in one cell.I asked Question for this [How to make cell as non editable based on another cell value in Editable Grid in gxt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22610705/1903120). But I got the solution that doesn't working for me.I asked in Sencha,coderanch and some other forums,but still I didn't got solution.

Now I decided to migrate this to GXT 3.0.1.

I need an EditableGrid and need to disable and enable the cell editing based on the value in another Cell.Please suggest which grid is suitable for this in GXT 3.0.1 and how to migrate to GXT 2.2.3 to GXT 3.0.1.

Comment: Mainly I need to disable the cell based on the value in another cell .I created EditorGrid using GXt 2.2.3.AnyOne Please Help.

Comment: I think I am not able to migrate from GXT 2.x to GXT 3.0 because I am using GWT 2.3 .But GXT 3.x requires GWT 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by just using CSS. Instead thinking of disabling and enabling the cell, I just hide and show the cell using CSS. Below is my code which saves me to reach this requirement.

```
 GridCellRenderer<AttendanceCaseCreationModel> checkinRenderer=new GridCellRenderer<AttendanceCaseCreationModel>() {

        @Override
        public Object render(AttendanceCaseCreationModel model, String property,
                ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex,
                ListStore<AttendanceCaseCreationModel> store,
                Grid<AttendanceCaseCreationModel> grid) {

            String color="pink";
            if(eventcombo.getValue()!=null){


                if(eventcombo.getRawValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Forgot To Checkin") || 
                        eventcombo.getRawValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Mark/Modify Attendance")){
                    color="pink";
                }
                else{

                    config.style=config.style+ ";visibility: hidden;";
                }

            }

            config.style=config.style+ ";background-color:" + color  + ";";
            config.style=config.style+ ";display: block;";
            Object value = model.get(property);
            return value;

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont work with gxt 2.x.x. My friend trys to migrate from 2 to 3. And he use 2 and 3 parallel. So he start to build a new pages with gxt3 because if youll mix them you may have a big problems with layouts!
If you want to use gxt3 you should do sonething like this:

```
//Create grid
Grid<Plant> grid = new Grid(...);
//Create editable grid
GridEditing<Plant> editing = new GridInlineEditing<Plant>(editableGrid);

//add first editing column
TextField watchField = new TextField();
TextField targerField = new TextField();

watchField.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
      if(smtng) targerField.disable();
      else targetField.enable();
   }
}); 
editing.addEditor(cc1, watchField);
editing.addEditor(cc2, targetField);
```

So I think thats help you.

Comment: For a slightly more general solution, consider the `ValueChangeEvent` instead of ChangeEvent`.

Comment: I dont sure but ValueChange event triggers when focus out from textbo

Comment: Both trigger then, but ValueChangeEvent can also trigger in other cases, such as when setValue(..., true) is called, where 'true' in that case means 'also fire an event'. This also comes up when using something where the user didn't change the text, like the SpinnerFields, DateField, ComboBox.

Comment: Mainly I need to disable the cell based on the value in another cell .I created EditorGrid using GXt 2.2.3.AnyOne Please Help.