# Focus is not coming out from the TextField on mouse click in GXT EditorGrid in Chrome Browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt, gxt

I created an EditorGrid using GXT 2.2.3.In that grid,one column is with the TextField as Editor.My code is as below:

```
ColumnConfig checkinTimecolumn=new ColumnConfig();
        checkinTimecolumn.setId("checkinTime");
        checkinTimecolumn.setHeader("Check In Time");
        checkinTimecolumn.setWidth(80);
        checkinTimecolumn.setMenuDisabled(true);
        checkinTimecolumn.setSortable(false);
        checkinTimecolumn.setStyle("width:100%;");
        checkinTimecolumn.setStyle("padding-right:3px;");

        final TextField<String> checkintime = new TextField<String>();
        checkintime.setAllowBlank(true);  
        checkintime.setWidth(15);
        checkintime.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {

                String prevcheckIntime=ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinTime();
                String variable = checkintime.getRawValue().trim();
            //  Window.alert("Getting the previous time-->"+prevcheckIntime);

                if(variable != null & !variable.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {   
                    if(!variable.matches(REG_EXP))
                    {
                        if(prevcheckIntime!=null){
                            checkintime.setValue(prevcheckIntime);
                    setDuration(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate(), 
                                   checkintime.getRawValue(),
                                    ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutDate(),ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutTime());
                        }
                        else {
                        checkintime.clear();
                        setDuration(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate(), 
                                null,
                                ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutDate(), ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutTime());

                        }
                        MsgBox.info("Enter time in hh:mm format");
                            checkintime.focus();
                        return;
                    }
                    String [] a=variable.split(":");
                    if(Integer.parseInt(a[0])>24) {
                        if(prevcheckIntime!=null){
                            checkintime.setValue(prevcheckIntime);
                            setDuration(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate(), 
                                    checkintime.getRawValue(),
                                    ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutDate(), ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutTime());

                        }
                        else {
                        checkintime.clear();
                        setDuration(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate(), 
                                null,
                                ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutDate(), ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutTime());

                        }
                        MsgBox.info(variable+" is not a valid time. 00:00 to 23:59 are valid" );
                        checkintime.focus();
                        return;


                    }
                    else{
                        setDuration(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate(), 
                                checkintime.getRawValue(),
                                ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutDate(), ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutTime());

                    }
                }
                else {
                    setDuration(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate(), 
                            null,
                            ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutDate(), ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckoutTime());
                 }

            }
        });
        checkinTimecolumn.setRenderer(checkinRenderer);
        checkinTimecolumn.setEditor(new CellEditor(checkintime));
        checkinTimecolumn.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        configs.add(checkinTimecolumn);
```

Now the issue is if the after  clicking  on checkIntime field in the CheckInTime column, the focus is not coming out if I click on the some other place in the Gird.This issue is happening in Chrome only.It's working well in IE and Firefox.

Please suggest how to resolve this.

> UPDATE

[image: After Clicking On the TextField in the EditorGrid]

If the Click on other than the row with mouse,focus from the TextField is not coming out that is the issue And Tab Key also not working on this Grid.

Css that I am setting for proper alignment of the rows and columns is working fine in IE but not working fine in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Please anyone respond on this.

Comment: use `checkinTimecolumn.setStyle("width:100%;padding-right:3px;");` instead of multiple `setStyle()` method calls.

Comment: @Braj  I will try this on tomorrow and let u know

Comment: Please share minimal compilable testable code to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below sample code first and Let me know if still there is any issue with this sample as well. It's working fine for me in all browsers.

I am using [gxt-2.2.3-gwt22.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/gxt/gxt-2.2.3-gwt22.jar.zip).

Sample code:

```
public class EXTJSGXT implements EntryPoint {

    private EditorGrid<ModelData> grid;
    private ListStore<ModelData> gridStore;
    private ColumnModel cm;

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        grid();
    }

    private void grid() {

        ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
        cp.setSize(450, 150);

        List<ColumnConfig> configs = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();

        List<String> eventList = new ArrayList<String>();
        eventList.add("Mark/Modify Attendance");
        eventList.add("Remove Attendance");
        eventList.add("Modify Roster");
        eventList.add("Mark OD");
        eventList.add("Forgot To Checkin");

        final SimpleComboBox<String> eventcombo = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
        eventcombo.setEmptyText("");
        eventcombo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
        CellEditor eventComboEditor = new CellEditor(eventcombo) {
            public Object preProcessValue(Object value) {
                if (value == null) {
                    return value;
                }
                return eventcombo.findModel(value.toString());
            }

            public Object postProcessValue(Object value) {
                if (value == null) {
                    return value;
                }
                return ((ModelData) value).get("value");
            }
        };
        eventcombo.setForceSelection(true);
        eventcombo.setEmptyText("");
        eventcombo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
        eventcombo.add(eventList);

        ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("event");
        column.setHeader("Co Manager/Distributor");
        column.setEditor(eventComboEditor);
        column.setWidth(200);
        configs.add(column);

        ColumnConfig column2 = new ColumnConfig();
        column2.setId("test");
        column2.setHeader("Test");
        column2.setEditor(new CellEditor(new TextField<String>()));
        column2.setWidth(100);
        configs.add(column2);

        ColumnConfig column3 = new ColumnConfig();
        column3.setId("desk");
        column3.setHeader("Desk");
        column3.setEditor(new CellEditor(new TextField<String>()));
        column3.setWidth(105);
        configs.add(column3);

        cm = new ColumnModel(configs);
        gridStore = new ListStore<ModelData>();
        ModelData md = new BaseModelData();
        md.set("checkinTime", "12-12-2003");
        md.set("event", "Modify Roster");
        md.set("test", "A1");
        md.set("desk", "A2");
        gridStore.add(md);

        md = new BaseModelData();
        md.set("checkinTime", "13-12-2003");
        md.set("event", "Remove Attendance");
        md.set("test", "B1");
        md.set("desk", "B2");
        gridStore.add(md);

        md = new BaseModelData();
        md.set("checkinTime", "14-12-2003");
        md.set("event", "Mark OD");
        md.set("test", "C1");
        md.set("desk", "C2");
        gridStore.add(md);

        gridStore.commitChanges();

        grid = new EditorGrid<ModelData>(gridStore, cm);
        grid.setBorders(true);
        grid.setStripeRows(true);
        grid.setTrackMouseOver(true);
        grid.disableTextSelection(false);
        grid.setHideHeaders(false);
        grid.setHeight(500);
        grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

        Viewport viewport = new Viewport();
        viewport.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        cp.add(grid);
        viewport.add(cp, new FitData(new Margins(0, 0, 56, 0)));
        RootPanel.get().add(viewport);
    }

}
```

---

--EDIT--

**need to disable the cell of that particular row only.But now it's disabling the entire column.**

Try with `BeforeEdit` listener and call `event.setCancelled(true)` on the basis of your condition to disable the editing.

```
    grid.addListener(Events.BeforeEdit, new Listener<GridEvent<ModelData>>() {
        public void handleEvent(GridEvent<ModelData> be) {

            ModelData data = be.getModel();
            String val = data.get("event");
            if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("Remove Attendance")) {
                if (be.getColIndex() == 2) { // disable 2nd cell only
                    be.setCancelled(true);// Disable edition
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: grid.getColumnModel().getColumnById("desk").getEditor().disable();  disabling the whole column

Comment: What do mean by disabling the whole column? Isn't it right behavior?

Comment: I need to disable the cell of that particular row only.But now it's disabling the entire column.

Comment: What is the difference between cell and column? Isn't it same thing?

Comment: cell in that particular row should be enabled or disabled based on the value in event combo box.But now If I Select 'Remove Attendance',It's disabling checkinDate column like in other rows also it's disabling the checkindate

Comment: OK now it got it. Let me check. What about your new issues?

Comment: Now look at edited section. Remove previous listener.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52272/discussion-between-ganesh-and-braj)

Comment: Have your tried it in Firefox? Are you testing it with my sample first?

Comment: Yes I tested on FireFox also

Comment: I am using **GWT 2.5**.

Comment: I have sent you a mail. Please validate and let me whether its working for you or not. If yes then I'will update it in my post as well.

Comment: Just now I tried it.Its working fine for disabling and enabling the cell.But I need to change the color of cell if it is editable.And Right now this is not the actual issue for me.