# on Tab Key press,focus in not going to next field in GXT EditorGrid

Tags: java, gwt, grid, gxt

I created an EditorGrid using GXT 2.2.3.The situation is, where if I press tab key, it will not automatically move to the next editing cell in the Grid.Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please anyone respond on this.

Comment: Please can your share your code to analyze it?

Comment: @Braj Please share your mail id ,I will send the code

Comment: May be the cell is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have already shared you a [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467057/focus-is-not-coming-out-from-the-textfield-on-mouse-click-in-gxt-editorgrid-in-c/23533443#23533443) that is working fine for me but not for you as discussed.

It might be issue with the `GXT 2.2.3.jar` that you are using.

Please can your try with **[gxt-2.2.3-gwt22.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467057/focus-is-not-coming-out-from-the-textfield-on-mouse-click-in-gxt-editorgrid-in-c/23533443#23533443)**.

Comment: But this one is not working in my case even if I changed the jar and code also

Comment: Have you tried with sample code first? There may be some issue within your code itself.

Comment: Just now I tried it.Its working fine for disabling and enabling the cell.But I need to change the color of cell if it is editable.And Right now this is not the actual issue for me.

Comment: We are not doing any cell to be disabling and enabling. we are just cancelling the edit for particular cell based on condition.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you any more. I have provided everything that I have along with jars, resources, code and complete sample project.

Comment: I can delete my post if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.No need to delete your answer.It may help someone else.